# Why can we remove the half-step velocity in velocity Verlet

Tags: integration

[image]

> Eliminating the half-step velocity, this algorithm may be shortend to

Why can we eliminate the half-step velocity and all the math behind the velocity Verlet to what Wikipedia shows?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you are asking - in the four step step just substituting equation 1 into equations 2 and 4 gives the three step version under the assumptions described at the bottom. Is that all you want?